# How to parse a link "href" tag from an XML in Swift?

Tags: xml, swift, parsing

I'm working on an app in Swift 3.0 that parses an XML file and displays some of the attributes via labels. Most of it is working properly, except for when I try to parse the part of the XML that contains a 
`<link href = "..."/>` tag. When I attempt to do this, the app crashes and I get a "Fatal error: index out of range" message. 
Here's the XML I'm using: https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/fl.php?x=0 
And here's my code:

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
    if(elementName == "cap:event") {
        titleFound = true
    }
    if(elementName == "cap:expires") {
        descFound = true
    }
    if(elementName == "cap:severity") {
        sevFound = true
    }
    if(elementName == "summary") {
        summFound = true
    }
    if(elementName == "cap:effective") {
        effFound = true
    }
    if(elementName == "cap:urgency") {
        urgFound = true
    }
    if(elementName == "cap:certainty") {
        certFound = true
    }
    if(elementName == "link") {
        linkFound = true
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if(elementName == "cap:event") {
        titleFound = false
    }
    if(elementName == "cap:expires") {
        descFound = false
    }
    if(elementName == "cap:severity") {
        sevFound = false
    }
    if(elementName == "summary") {
        summFound = false
    }
    if(elementName == "cap:effective") {
        effFound = false
    }
    if(elementName == "cap:urgency") {
        urgFound = false
    }
    if(elementName == "cap:certainty") {
        certFound = false
    }
    if(elementName == "link") {
        linkFound = false
    }
}
```

The element I want is the link href tag from inside the `<entry>` tag. I'm not sure how to go about properly parsing this part since it's not formatted like the other tags (`<cap:event>`, `<cap:severity>`, etc.) Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `didStartElement` method, you can access that attribute through the parameter `attributeDict` which should return `["href":"www.whatever.com"]`

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397907/handling-an-attribute-of-an-xml-element-in-swift)

Is this for Tanksale's CS320 Midterm? Regardless, good luck!

Comment: Hah, it is indeed! I was wondering if anyone from that class would find this question when searching for help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around but check the xml doc the id tag contains the url as well.

I was having the same problem. Chirp Chirp!